# Draw polylines under the street name in mapbox_maps_flutter

Tags: flutter, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android

Greeting Everyone,

```
            
await mapboxContorller.create(
        PolylineAnnotationOptions(
              geometry: LineString(
                coordinates: [
                  Position(
                    startPoint.coordinates.longitude,
                    startPoint.coordinates.latitude,
                  ),
                  Position(
                    endPoint.coordinates.longitude,
                    endPoint.coordinates.latitude,
                  ),
                ],
              ).toJson(),
              lineColor: lineColor,
              lineWidth: 8.0,
              lineJoin: LineJoin.ROUND,
        ),
);
```

I can draw PolyLines and Multiple Polylines over the map by the above code, but Polylines are drawn on the Street name. I am using coordinates from a JSON file to draw the line. I cannot switch input data to GeoJson, client requirement.

Is there a way to draw Polylines under the street name

I could not try anything much, as there is no default way to show street names for Polylines in
[mapbox_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/mapbox_maps_flutter) package

Comment: If I understand your question, this is an issue of layer order, you need to add your layer before the street layer. How do you create your layer?

One way of affecting the order is using the `beforeId` parameter of the addLayer method (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#addlayer) or the moveLayer method to move your layer to the right place